# What "Current" properties flow with ExecutionContext

Tags: .net, multithreading, async-await

This is a two part question:

1. Can someone provide a list of the ASP.NET/.NET properties that are typically thread local that flow with ExecutionContext?

   HttpContext.Current?
   Thread.CurrentContext?
   Thread.CurrentPrincipal?
   Thread.CurrentCulture?

   What properties can I count on surviving/persisting async/await?

   What else?
2. Is there any way to add application specific Context information that will flow automatically with ExecutionContext?  Something like

   ```
   var ec = ExecutionContext.Capture();
   ec.CustomContext["MyCustomContext"] = ACustomContext;
   ```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?  Why do you feel the need to store a custom context?

Comment: If you have two separate questions, *you should ask two questions*.

Comment: @ReedCopsey, I'm trying to refactor some legacy code that makes use of ThreadStatic and other thread local storage mechanism so that it will play nice with async/await.

Comment: @JoeEnzminger, you may want to check this: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/executioncontext.cs#3a777fa35a9f1ffe

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The best resource for this is [ExecutionContext vs. SynchronizationContext](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/executioncontext-vs-synchronizationcontext/) by Stephen Toub. There is no list of properties like what you're looking for.

ASP.NET actually uses `SynchronizationContext` to flow `HttpContext.Current`, and [treats `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` rather oddly](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SystemThreadingThreadCurrentPrincipalVsSystemWebHttpContextCurrentUserOrWhyFormsAuthenticationCanBeSubtle.aspx).

You can add your own context using `LogicalSetData`/`LogicalGetData`. However, you should only store immutable data. I document this [on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/implicit-async-context-asynclocal.html).

Comment: Thanks (for LogicalSetData/LogicalGetData).  I'd read each article you mentioned already, but it still left open the question of what framework context's flow.  Seems like something that would be important to document...

Comment: @JoeEnzminger: BTW, I don't *recommend* logical get/set data. It's just *possible* to use if you can't find another solution. I haven't run benchmarks but I would expect it's much slower than `ThreadStatic`. Explicit method arguments or instance fields would be my solution of choice.

Comment: +1. It's interesting to see what actually gets flowed, albeit undocumented: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/executioncontext.cs#3a777fa35a9f1ffe. Especially interesting how synchronization context gets flowed explicitly via `ExecutionContext.Run`, but not implicitly.

Comment: @Noseratio if you read Toub's linked article (specifically the last paragraphs) you'll see that `SynchrnoizationContext` is actually **not** flowed most of the time (not sure what you meant by explicitly/implicitly).

Comment: @OhadSchneider, by *explicitly* I meant calling `ExecutionContext.Capture` and `ExecutionContext.Run` explicitly. By *implicitly* I meant just letting the async/await infrastructure flow it.