# How should I use ExecutionContext to provide flow of my own context?

Tags: asp.net, executioncontext

**Update:**

Found similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17242094/what-current-properties-flow-with-executioncontext).

I want to implement some services following AmbientContext design pattern for our ASP.NET application.
For example I need user name (like Thread.CurrentPrincipal) to be set once at the very beginning of the request processing and flow between threads when async operations are performed.
Thus I need to attach data to ExecutionContext and then detach it when request is processed.

Unfortuantely, I have no idea, how to do it.

There is only a small hint in [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.executioncontext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Internally, the ExecutionContext stores all data that is associated
>   with the LogicalCallContext. This allows the LogicalCallContext data
>   to be propagated when the ExecutionContext is copied and transferred.

Comment: Being non the wiser as to the difference between a SynchronisationContext (which I was going to suggest making use of) and ExecutionContext I arrived here via google: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/06/15/executioncontext-vs-synchronizationcontext.aspx

Comment: @brumScouse Exactly from this article I came to the conclusion that ExecutionContext is more appropriate being a more general thing than SynchronizationContext.

Comment: @brumScouse the only thing I had to do to get the answer is to read comments under the article =)

Comment: Maybe I should have read a bit more in depth!   Nice one, I'll read those with interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same question. I eventually found the [CallContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.messaging.callcontext.aspx) class, which can do this using the `LogicalGetData` and `LogicalSetData` methods. Here's a [very good article with examples](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/implicit-async-context-asynclocal.html) that discusses how to use this class.

Comment: Yes, I saw Stephen's article after I  eventually wrote my own but very similar implementation.

Comment: Make sure to use LogicalSetData/LogicalGetData to preserve data between async calls (e.g. when you call database or API)-  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.remoting.messaging.callcontext?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2