# Set HttpContext.Current is not the same in continuation of await

Tags: asp.net, httpcontext, synchronizationcontext

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17242222/11129932) answer from Stephen Cleary, I understand that the `HttpContext` flows with the `SynchronizationContext`. Therefore, given the following piece of code:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        var outerContext = System.Web.HttpContext.Current = new HttpContext(
            new HttpRequest(null, "http://test.com", null),
            new HttpResponse(new StreamWriter("C:/Path")));

        Console.WriteLine(outerContext.Equals(System.Web.HttpContext.Current));

        await Task.Run(
            delegate
            {
                Console.WriteLine(outerContext.Equals(System.Web.HttpContext.Current));
            });
        
        Console.WriteLine(outerContext.Equals(System.Web.HttpContext.Current));
        
        return View();
    }
```

I would expect the console output to be:

```
True
False
True
```

However, the actual output is:

```
True
False
False
```

After debugging, it appears that the context in the continuation is set to the original context of the request, the one it had before I manually set it by calling `HttpContext.Current = ...`. What is the reason for this? Does it get set to the request context somewhere before the code after the `await` gets executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HttpContext.Current` value is *not* saved and restored by `await`. `await` will capture `SynchronizationContext.Current` and use that to resume execution.

When the request starts, a new request context is created (which includes a specific `HttpContext.Current` instance). Whenever `AspNetSynchronizationContext` resumes execution on that request context, it sets `HttpContext.Current` to the instance for that request context.

So, after the `await`, `HttpContext.Current` will be the same instance it was at the beginning of `Index`, not whatever instance your code assigns to it.